# Triangle and Gaussian Distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_6$ be six independent standard Gaussian distributions $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Consider a triangle on the plane with vertices $A_1 = (X_1, X_2), A_2 = (X_3, X_4), A_3 = (X_5, X_6)$. How can I prove that the length of the side $A_2A_3$ is independent from the length of the median $A_1M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $M$ is the midpoint of $A_2A_3$.

You can show more than that: That $M$ is independent of the length of $A_2A_3$. (It follows immediately that the length of $A_1M$ is, too.)

To show this, write $M=\frac{A_2+A_3}2$ and $D=\frac{A_2-A_3}2$; then

$$
\exp\left(-A_2^2\right)\exp\left(-A_3^2\right)=\exp\left(-(M+D)^2-(M-D)^2\right)=\exp\left(-2M^2\right)\exp\left(-2D^2\right)\;.
$$

Thus $M$ and $D$ are independent, and thus also $M$ and $|A_2A_3|=2|D|$.